# HTML 5 Video becomes corrupted when setting currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

After the video ends i want it to be played again, but this time from a different start time. I have added a video ended event handler :

```
video.addEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnd);
```

And my handleVideoEnd looks like this:

```
function handleVideoEnd(e) {
    if (currentVideo.loop) {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        video.currentTime = 1;
        video.play();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when i use that code my video becomes corrupted for a couple of seconds resulting in that effect: http://screenshot.sh/m1UaF580NNx8B
This problem, however does not appear if i set the currentTime to 0.

I'm using webm video and testing it in chrome currently. Did anyone have a similar issue when seeking a video part?

Comment: the problem is key frames - look it up and understand

Comment: So i need to directly hit this one key frame inside a video so that will start playing it without corrupting it? And second 1 is just not one of those right?

Comment: as close as possible on or before

Comment: Okey - is there any way of getting key frames out of a video? Or do i have to know them myself?

Comment: dynamically in javascript? not sure to be honest

Comment: I have one question tho - if i set a source to be like xxx.webm#t=1,5 it works correctly without any corruption.

Comment: are you saying it does work that way? or asking if it would?

Comment: I'm saying it works that way if i start a video with src with #t set to value as above. It won't work the next tiem i try to play it.

Comment: odd - so this is an external (to your site) video - youtube?

Comment: No this is an internal video that im playing locally.

Comment: so, how does your server handle the `#t=` part of the request?

Comment: the #t= part is handled by the browser right? The server retrieves a video correctly, because the first play is always working correctly.

Comment: `the #t= part is handled by the browser right?` as part of a video src attribute? no, #t= means nothing to a browser in this repsect ... `the first play is always working correctly` - the first play starts at 0:00:00.000 - guaranteed to be a key frame

Comment: Nope if i set the video src to be xxx.webm#t=2,5 it will start on the second 2 and play for 5 seconds and then call my handler. However if i set the currentTime again to second 2 it fails.

Comment: oh ... wow ... I never knew that!!!

Comment: Now I have to rethink everything I've said to you!!!

Comment: If you have any solution idea to that problem please post one: )
as for #t:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: This is why I love SO ... in trying to help someone, I've learned something new ... sorry I can't help though ... I am surprised that a video that is fully loaded can't be played from any frame! yet can be started seemingly at any

Comment: P.S. that documentation isn't quite right ... it says `it can only be used when specifying the source for media elements, and not in the address bar` ... I can assure you it works in the address bar!!

Comment: @JaromandaX yes you are, src works directly on chrome (dunno about other browsers). On the other hand i took another video and it worked correctly :) seems like my .webm test video could have been encoded with some weird stuff. Thanks for the help tho :)